# How to correctly merge multiple csv files in Python

Tags: python, csv, merge, concatenation

How can I correctly merge multiple csv files with, in most cases, different column names between each file?
I have tried using .concat() in the following code:

```
import os, glob
path = "mypath/"
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f, sep=',') for f in all_files)
df_merged   = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, axis=0,
    join="outer",
    ignore_index=False,
    keys=None,
    levels=None,
    names=None,
    verify_integrity=False,
    copy=True,)
df_merged.to_csv('mypath/my_new_file.csv')

my_new_file = pd.read_csv ('mypath/my_new_file.csv', sep=',')
print(my_new_file.head(40))
print(my_new_file.columns)
```

I know some of the .csv share some column names but they don't get merged correctely. Am I missing something?

Do you advice using .merge() instead?
Thank you

Comment: A sample with some lines of 3 different csv files can help.

Comment: What do the different csv files look like? Specifically, what do you mean by 'different column names between each file'? Are they theoretically the same columns just the lables differ, or are there completely different columns in the files? By what logic should they get concatenated in this case?

Comment: maybe rename columns to have the same names in all files. OR show example files and expected result. And explain `"don't get merged correctely"` - show what you get and what you expected. Without example this question has no solution because we don't know what exactly you expect.